# How to create ASP.NET Identity users on startup/manually with the Web template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core

I don't seem to get it. I just want to create some users from the VS2015 Web core template (ideally from a core console app but that seems to require more setup)

So I call Initialize from the Startup.cs

UserManager is NULL so it does not work. What am I missing?

DbInitializer.Initialize(context);

```
  public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }


    public static async void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "abc@xxx.com" };
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");


        //var ttime = DateTime.Now;
        //for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        //{
        //    var start = DateTime.Now;

        //    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        //    {
        //        var email = "user" + ((j * 100) + i) + "@constoso.com";
        //        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "Bob", Email = email };
        //        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "ccc");
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing your UserManager anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist to call it from the Startup, pass on the ServiceProvider and get the Usermanager from that one:

`DbInitializer.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);`

```
public static async void Initialize(IServiceProvider services)
{
    using (var scope = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope()) {
        var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "abc@xxx.com" };
        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent.. now I just need to figure out if this make more sense to be a console app as part of data etl... or in the web site itself and part of the init.... I'm thinking the web site since by the point I create it the aspnet identity tables will exist

Comment: @punkouter it's a one-time thing right? I think it only makes sense for demo purposes to put it in the web app. Otherwise I would create a simple console app, run it once and throw it away ;-). In the web app initialize it will be checked each time you start your web application and that doesn't make sense.